# What 3rd party app do I need to install to make Ctrl+Shift switch input language?

Tags: 18.04, gtk, input-language

I can not make Ctrl+Shift switch input language. What do I do? The app that adjust hot keys don't react when I press Ctrl+Shift. Please help!